# After upgrading to Eclipse Juno, changes in Facelets pages are not reflected until project is restarted

Tags: eclipse, jsf, facelets

After I upgraded to Eclipse Juno, when I modify a Facelets page, then I have to re-run the project to see the modifications. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Use the JBoss Tools that are available in the Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: Did you have automatic builds enabled then but not now?  Is it the same kind of server that you're launching then and now?

Comment: I haven't tried Juno yet, but do you have a `javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE` context param in `web.xml` which is set to `Development`? If not, give it a try. Just to exclude the JSF implementation from being suspect. It should actually not matter, but you never know for sure in an IDE. By the way, when you said "re-run the project" don't you actually mean "restart the server"? Further I've deleted your second question. You should ask a separate question for that (only not here, it's namely not constructive).

Comment: Sorry my answer is little late, i did try to change my jsf configuration to Development but still not working, automatic build is enabled too.